# INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]: Trigger.alteration: line 54, column 1

Tags: id

```
trigger alteration on OpportunityLineItem (before insert) {
  Set<id> opps=new Set<id>();
  Map<id,Opportunity> maps=new Map<id,Opportunity>();

  Map<id,id> let=new Map<id,id>();

  Map<id,id> skipbillmap=new Map<id,id>();


  For(OpportunityLineItem ol :trigger.new)
    {
    opps.add(ol.OpportunityId);
    let.put(ol.OpportunityId,ol.product2ID);
    }

      List<Opportunity> opp=[select Id,StageName from Opportunity Where id IN :opps];


        For(Opportunity op:opp) 
        { 

        System.debug('-----------stagename----------'+op.StageName);

        IF(op.StageName == 'Closed Won')
            {
               maps.put(op.id,op);
            }         
        }

    List<billing__c> skipbill=[select id,Name,trigger__c from billing__c where trigger__c IN:opps];

    List<billing__c> billingList=[select id,Name,trigger__c,price__c,quantity__c from billing__c where trigger__c IN:opps];

    For(Billing__c bil : skipbill)
    {
        skipbillmap.put(bil.trigger__c,bil.id);
    }    


    For(OpportunityLineItem obj :trigger.new)
    {
        if(skipbillmap.containsKey(obj.opportunityID)== false){

                 billing__c line=new  billing__c();

                    line.price__c=obj.UnitPrice;
                    line.quantity__c=obj.Quantity;
                    line.trigger__c=obj.opportunityid;
                    billingList.add(line);
         }
    }
    If(billingList.isEmpty() == false)
    {
      insert billingList;
    }


  List<billingline__c>blne=new List<billingline__c>();
  List<billing__c> rat=[select id,price__c,quantity__c,trigger__c from billing__c];

  for (billing__c cat:billingList)
  {

 billingline__c nline  =  new billingline__c();
   nline.price__c=cat.price__c;
   nline.quantity__c=cat.quantity__c;
   nline.billing__c=cat.id;
  nline.prod_lookup__c= let.get(cat.trigger__c);
   blne.add(nline);


  }
  insert blne; 

     }
```

Comment: Hi jassi.  Do you have a specific question to ask?

Comment: yess    Apex trigger alteration caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: alteration: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0728000000iRzxAAE; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]: Trigger.alteration: line 54, column 1

Comment: i wont able to solve this error

Answer (score 1):

You haven't asked a question, but I assume you're asking "how can I fix the error above?".  Please read the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask better questions in the future.

As the error states, you cannot `insert` sObjects with IDs already specified.  You're getting the error because the Billing__c sObjects in `billingList` already contain IDs.  Why is that?

Well, if we look at this line:

```
List<billing__c> billingList=[select id,Name,trigger__c,price__c,quantity__c from billing__c where trigger__c IN:opps];
```

We see that you're retrieving existing Billing__c sObjects (with existing IDs), and trying to insert them again - hence the error.

It's hard to tell what the solution is, because your code is unclear and you haven't included any explanation in your question.  I suspect that you need to create and use a separate new `List` to store the Billing__c sObjects that you're inserting on line 54.

Comment: i just want to ask how can i fix ,

Comment: how can i write list now

Comment: @jassi - You have all the information you need to fix it. There are so many other issues (SOQL inside for loop as one if them) though you really should do so reading on how to write a trigger and Apex Best practices. Start at the trailhead site. The issue you are asking about is due to a fundemental misunderstanding of how to write triggers.

Comment: is there anyone who teach me how to write trigger